# How to get the battery temperature value on ios 10?

Tags: ios, iphone, percentage, battery

[image]

I have found this application on App store in which they are showing battery temperature value. Can anyone help me to know how they are doing it?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Please read my question carefully. As I mentioned this API doesn't works on iOS 10.

Comment: **Refer this link for more information:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346230/how-to-obtain-extensive-battery-info-in-ios

Comment: It may not be possible on iOS 10. According to the guy who wrote UIDeviceListener, the temp in that screenshot is fake. (See where a similar screenshot shows up in this thread: https://github.com/eldade/UIDeviceListener/issues/6 )